# How to move image down in css

Tags: html, css

so I was making a search engine and posting it to the public, but I want the image to move down and center, here's my code:

```css
img {
  background-position: bottom 45px bottom;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  outline-style: solid
}
```

```html
<div id="outline-style">
   <div id="margin-bottom">
        <img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/CqUZKaQT0aKsKN4s6QLmO_2lsIoFqxMCpWGdGjA_WFdTcEsdIDEXvDSBl8YT7TwqpUC50zHHq_X-MIy5Onl-WKDjP7IBvoPG-P5CZHr6OmC__zLeZfRJN3v79eqB3GkP6720yegWc9HD_rMfFbsD96v3NYqwFAQgcN09MqY1QqxuCnzPu4QFEGCS5Qt-OLyQwZWMf4E9RdnPkf2QqQPwbXYStw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://dynamic.brandcrowd.com/preview/logodraft/086197e5-30cd-4bd5-abc0-e3ff2882e5a0/image/large.png?bust=ad19d638-d125-45ae-b59a-278e4976924f"
          width="200px" height="200px">
   </div>
</div
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: also it was not working, i don't now what happend

Answer (score 1):

You may adjust the **position and padding** of the image.

> Here's a reference of the difference between margin and padding:
>
> [https://www.javatpoint.com/margin-vs-padding#:~:text=tabulated%20as%20follows%3A-,Margin,inside%20of%20the%20element's%20border](https://www.javatpoint.com/margin-vs-padding#:%7E:text=tabulated%20as%20follows%3A-,Margin,inside%20of%20the%20element%27s%20border).

You might need to make it into **position: absolute** if necessary

> Learn more about positioning here:
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try one of these things:

Position: relative;
top: -10; (maybe +)

or

margin-top: -10%